# Export a local image (dd) to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

I have a local server with Linux configured with very specific tools that I want to upload to the cloud.

Can I export a local HDD image copied with dd into an Amazon EC2 instance to save the time I spent setting up the local server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is documented by AWS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/). In short, you would have to convert your image into a virtual machine disk and upload it to AWS using the command line tools.